# Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AppProvider)"

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm developing a react-native app with expo.

I've reach a point when some shared store is needed between my components, so I turned to redux.

But, after a few hours struggling, I could not get it working: I keep getting the infamous error "Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AppProvider)"".

However, everything looks fine to me. I don't understand where the error comes from. Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux' 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import App from './App.js'
import store from './store/store.js'
import { setNCServer, setToken } from './store/actions';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
 
const AppProvider = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
}
 
// Initialise store
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({
      setNCServer,
      setToken,
    }, dispatch)
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
};
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
const AppRoot = connector(AppProvider);
export default registerRootComponent(AppRoot);
```

Here is my store.js file:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import CombinedReducers from './reducers.js';
 
const store = createStore(CombinedReducers);
 
export default store
```

Here is my reducers.js file:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const tokenReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'set':
        return action.payload;  
    default:
      return state
  }
};

const NCServerReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'set':
        return action.payload;  
    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default combinedReducers({
  NCServer: NCServerReducer,
  token: tokenReducer
});
```

And here's my action.js file:

```js
export const setNCServer = NCServer => (
  {
    type: 'set',
    payload: NCServer,
  }
);

export const setToken = token => (
  {
    type: 'set',
    payload: token,
  }
);
```

======== UPDATE =========

Following Pera's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67746329/16063826), I've tried to move my `connect` logic in the `App` component.

Not really sure how to do that, my `index.js` file now looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux' ;
import App from './App.js';
import store from './store/store.js';
 
export default class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

And my `App.js` file, like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

// Persistent storage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { setNCServer, setToken } from './store/actions';
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';
import BoardScreen from './BoardScreen';
import BoardDetailsScreen from './BoardDetailsScreen';
import CardDetailsScreen from './CardDetailsScreen';

// For creating an URL handler to retrieve the device token
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

// Create Stack navigator
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// Application
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    // Retrieve token from storage if available
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then(token => {
      this.props.state.setToken(token)  
    })

    // Register handler to catch Nextcloud's redirect after successfull login
    Linking.addEventListener('url', (url) => {this.handleRedirect(url)})
  }

  // Function to retrieve the device's token and save it after user logged in
  handleRedirect = async (url) => {
    if (url.url.startsWith('nc://login/server')) {
      try {
        token = url.url.substring(url.url.lastIndexOf(':'))
        console.log('Persisting token', token)
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);  
        this.props.state.setToken(token)
      } catch (e) {
        // TODO
      } 
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.token === null) {
      // No token is stored yet, we need to get one
      return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      ) 
    } else {
      return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="AllBoard" component={BoardScreen} options={{title: 'All boards'}} />
              <Stack.Screen name="BoardDetails" component={BoardDetailsScreen} options={{title: 'Board details'}} />
              <Stack.Screen name="CardDetails" component={CardDetailsScreen} options={{title: 'Card details'}} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
  }
}

// Initialise store
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    setNCServer,
    setToken,
  }, dispatch)
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
};
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
const AppRoot = connector(App);
export default registerRootComponent(AppRoot);
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

The error logs look a bit strange to me:

```
Info Before connect
13:04
Info After connect
13:04
Info before createStore CombinedReducers: [Function combination]
13:04
Info after createStore 
13:04
Info Running application on Mon iPhone.
13:04
Error Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.
13:04

This error is located at:
    in Connect(App) (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

So, when I start the app, it goes over the `connect` and the `createStore` functions and fails later in `ExpoRoot`.... What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are trying to use `connect` before actually initializing the Redux context with the store.
Try using `connect` with the `App` component instead, that way `AppProvider` has already rendered and the store is setup.

Comment: Well, your problem statement makes sense: I can imagine such an issue in my app. However, I fail to understand your solution.
I've tried moving the `connect` function to `App` but it didn't solve the issue.
I'll edit my question to try to give more information

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out: the main problem was that `export default registerRootComponent();` must be in `index.js`